# How can i retrieve a specific data from nodes in firebase and display to lisltview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already have knowledge in retrieving data from firebase. The thing is, the data i want to retrieve lies under 3 parent nodes, and I can't figure any way how to retrieve data from the database 3 nodes deep. What I want is to get all the values of the key named "name" and display it in a listview.

[image]

Comment: You can chain multiple calls to `getDatabaseReference()` or add slashes between keys... `"medicine-handook/Medicines"`... Then you query it like normal..  What code have you been trying that isn't working?

Comment: first of all get reference of Medicines and iterate its children from data snapshot and get value of key "name".

Comment: I haven't tried to experiment yet, I just searched anywhere in hoping for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display all those names, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference medicinesRef = rootRef.child("Medicines");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
medicinesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
amoxcillin
paracetamol
mefenamic
```

Comment: Thanks man, but it only returns mefenamic :(    i tried displaying it on a Toast, and next i tried adding it to my arraylist but only returns mefenamic

Comment: Tell me if the all the names are present in the logcat, when using `Log.d("TAG", name);`?

Comment: Yes they are present in the logcat;                                                  03-02 20:59:30.232 3381-3381/? D/TAG: amoxcillin  <br/>
03-02 20:59:30.232 3381-3381/? D/TAG: paracetamol  <br/>
03-02 20:59:30.232 3381-3381/? D/TAG: mefenamic  <br/>

Comment: That's perfect. The code works. If you'll get only the `mefenamic` in your list is because most likely you are setting the adapter in the foor loop. Get it out and try again? Does it work?

Comment: No the the adapter is not inside the for loop, it lies just beneath the codes you've given me, btw it gave me nullpointer exception earlier doing so

Comment: Edit your question with the updated code, so I can take a look.

Comment: Actually it did work when i placed the adapter inside the loop. Thanks man you're a life saver. But the listview item's font color turned white, how strange